# Finish a game after complete

Tags: actionscript-3, null, pong

I've been doing a game like pong. But when the ball hit in some letters that i've got on the stage some letters disappears. My letters are movieclip and basically i'm doing an if statement like this:

```
if(mcBall.hitTestObject(mc2)){      
    removeChild(mc2);
    mc2 = null;
}
```

What i want to know is what the best way to tell the program to finish the game when the all the letters disappears. 
I thought to use the null property like this: 
if (mc1 && mc2 && mc3 = null){
gotoscene x
} 
Is that possible? Use null objects to tell the program to go to another scene?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the children your removing from the container are the only children you could use `if (numChildren == 0){gotoscene x}`, if there not the only children then take a sample of that variable before you add them to compare. `if (numChildren == numChildrenPreInt){//}`

Another method would be to store your collision objects in an ArrayCollection, implementing something like this:

```
private var collisionObjs:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

private function init():void{
collisionObjs.addItem(nc1); //do this for all your objects.
}

private function isComplete():Boolean
{
return (collisionObjs.length == 0);
}

private function detectCollision():void
{
if(mcBall.hitTestObject(mc2)){      
removeChild(mc2);
collisionObjs.removeItemAt(collisionObjs.getItemIndex(mc2));
if (isComplete())
{
//goto complete
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should employ an Array of objects (bricks, letters, no matter what), and once an object is hit, remove it from screen and from the array, and once the array is empty, go wherever you want.

```
var letters:Array=new Array();
letters.push(mc1); 
// stuff all of your removable objects in a level in here
letters.push(mcN);
```

Then you repeatedly check for each of them, if they collide with the ball, you do like this:

```
for (var i:int=letters.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
    var tmc=letters[i]; 
    if (mcBall.hitTestObject(tmc)) {
       tmc.parent.removeChild(tmc);
       letters.splice(i,1);
       if (letters.length==0) { 
           // goto complete code (call a method, that makes the game go "you win")
       }
    } else {
       // do anything with tmc if you want. If not, omit this
    } 
}
```